# Getting oldest folder in a drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I have a drive of 20 terabyte .Now I want to get oldest folder in the drive and move it to other location.Linear search is making my service quite slow.Any solution on how to get the oldest folder from the drive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You may better ask this at serverfault.com (check which tools already exists for this)
2. stackoverflow.com is not a programming service.

Said this, a few things you should ask yourself and consider:

What do you mean exactly by "oldest folder". The timestamp of the folder itself is useless in most cases. My experiences in this area show that best you can do is enumerating all FILES and check the modification timestamp.

What I can recommend:

Write a tool which recursively enumerates all files on the drive and writes the information (path, file size, time stamps) to a text file.

Later you can read this file and can create lists e.g.
how many files / GB of data on the drive is older than 2 years, folder with the oldest files in it, how many files ending in .xls are older than 6 months...

> > Linear search is making my service quite slow.

There is no API "query the oldest folder". You have to scan the drive in one way or another.

So my answer is more of a non-answer, sorry...